# Retain Parent DataLabel in Treemap Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a TreeMap where it has one parent and the parent has two child. On clicking on parent, I want to fire an click event, so I have made "allowDrillToNode" to false. But when hovering on one the chart, the parent's datalabel is hiding. But I need the parent datalabel to be visible even when I hover on the chart. Code which I tried is in this fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/vgnshs/sfw8bjmL/

```js
$(function () {
  var points = [{
            "id" : "id_0",
            "name" : "Software"  ,
   "color":"rgb(64,64,64)",
            "value" : 50,
   
        }, {
            "id" : " ",
            "name" : ""  ,
   "color":"rgb(104,104,104)",
            "value" : 30,
            "parent" : "id_0"
   
        }, {
            "id" : " ",
            "name" : ""  ,
   "color":"rgb(184,184,184) ",
            "value" : 20,
            "parent" : "id_0"
   
        }
    ];
  var options ={    
        credits: {
            enabled: false   
        },      
        chart: {
           renderTo : "container"           
        },
      tooltip : {
                    enabled : false
                },
        series: [{
            type: "treemap",
            layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',           
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                hideWhenOverlap : false
            }, 
            levels: [{
                level: 1,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                borderWidth: 3
            }],
            events : {
                        click : function(drillDownevent) {
                           alert("click received");
                    }
            },            
            data: points
        }],
        title: {
            text: "TreeMap"
        }
    };
    var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);   
  
});
```

```css
#container {
 min-width: 300px;
 max-width: 600px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div><br/><br/>
```

Comment: To re-phrase the question, why is the parent label getting hidden? Basically Tree is in parent level and so parent Datalabel shouldn't get hidden.

Comment: datLabel's zIndex is changed when point is hovered - you would have to extend Highcharts by rewriting some code or just disable mouse tracking - http://jsfiddle.net/sfw8bjmL/2/

Comment: Hi Kacper. Disabling mouse tracking disables click event as well. In my case, click even should be fired without datalabel getting vanished. :(

Comment: To avoid extending Highcharts it it possible to add custom label and hide default dataLabels for series. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qgyg6d42/1/

Comment: Hi Kacper. Thanks a lot for the reply. That helped perfect. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just set useHTML property to true in dataLabels under level.

This work for me.

```
dataLabels: {
  useHTML: true,
  enabled: true,
  align: 'left',
  verticalAlign: 'top',
  style: {
    fontSize: '15px',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  }
}
```